# Html.CheckBoxFor in VB Razor View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this C# code in a Razor view:

```
@(Html.CheckBoxFor<RazorSamplesWeb.Models.SamplesModel>(i => i.IsActive))
```

I tried translating it to this:

```
@Code Html.CheckBoxFor(Of RazorSamplesWeb.Models.SamplesModel)(Function(i) i.IsActive)End Code
```

But it's complaining.  Why, and what is the right statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
@(Html.CheckBoxFor<RazorSamplesWeb.Models.SamplesModel>(i => i.IsActive))
```

is too long, ugly and equivalent to:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(i => i.IsActive)
```

which in VB.NET might look like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(i) i.IsActive)
```

The `@Code` you are referring to could be used for helpers which do not return any value (IHtmlString) but write directly to the output buffer. Example:

```
@Code Html.RenderAction("Foo") End Code
```

Comment: Yes, but similarly, let's assume I need the generic argument, for demonstration purposes.  When providing the model type, I get an error.  Without is working fine for me, but with, which should just work as expected, is not.

Comment: Although if option strict is on, it doesn't like the inferred type in Function (x) x.ExpressionTarget

Answer (score 0):

`@Code` blocks are used for standalone statements; they're equivalent to `@{ ... }` in C#.

You should use a raw `@` block.

Your C# code uses parentheses to force the parser to read past the HTML-like `<...>` portion.
VB.Net doesn't have ambiguous generics syntax, so you don't need it.

Comment: Try wrapping it in `()`.  Also, you shouldn't need to specify the generic parameter in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the @ModelType defined, the right statement is

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(m As RazorSamplesWeb.Models.SamplesModel) m.IsActive))
```

You explicitly set the generic type to RazorSamplesWeb.Models.SamplesModel.